Trouble storing very large data in Milvus vector-database?
I noticed that the string type in Milvus currently has a limitation of 64K bytes as its maximum size. While this works for most cases, I’m dealing with scenarios where the data I need to store exceeds this size constraint.
What are the best practices for efficiently storing larger strings or text data in Milvus? Specifically, I’m interested in exploring alternatives to manually splitting the data into smaller chunks. Are there any recommended strategies, approaches, or Milvus-native solutions that handle large data more effectively? Additionally, are there any potential limitations, performance considerations, or trade-offs to be aware of when working with large text data in Milvus?
